# Use jQuery's switchClass method to fade in an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is this possible? I've tried visibility:hidden/visibility:visible and display:none/display:block on the classes to switch between, but both result in the element popping in at the end.

Comment: Have you tried `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` ?

Comment: I want to do other things besides the fade at the same time. Switchclass doesn't seem to play nice with fadeIn \ fadeOut when chained either.

Comment: fadeIn and fadeOut are what you want.  Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

When styling the two classes, use the [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity) property.  `.swithClass` will be able to transition smoothly between varying opacities.

Example:

```
   .FadeFrom {
      opacity: 0.0;
   }

   .FadeTo {
      opacity: 1.0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here on how to implement [JQuery Fading](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/)

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

You can handle other events in the fade in and out using the call back function like this:

```
  $('.someClass').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // run extra code here
  });

  $('.someClass').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // run extra code here
  });
```

Comment: That's a callback when it's complete. What if I want something to slide from left: 50 to left: 100 while fading in using switchClass?

Comment: Nest two elements such as DIV and start the slide and the fade separately, each on one of the elements: http://old.nabble.com/combine-slide-and-fade-td21937832s27240.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `.animate()`

```
$("#myElement").animate({ opacity: 1, left: 0 }, 1000);
```

To get `.switchClass()` to work, you'll have to edit the jQuery code.  Find `function getElementStyles()`.  In the `else`, after `if (typeof style[key] === 'string') {` add this code:

```
if (key == "filter" && /^alpha\(opacity=(\d+)\)$/.test(style[key])) {
    newStyle.opacity = parseFloat(RegExp.$1) / 100;
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Yeah I know I can use animate. What I want to know is if switchClass can do alpha changes. I like switchClass because it lets you keep your animations in a css file and out of code.

Comment: Then no.  `.switchClass()` only operates on numeric values.  Since, in IE8 and below opacity is not numeric (ie, `parseInt()` returns `NaN`), this value is ignored during the animation.

Comment: Is there any way to override the getElementStyles method instead of altering the original jquery code?

Comment: Nope. It is a private function internal to the implementation of switchClass.  You can either modify the source or write your own switchClass plugin.